# Refreshing a page on button press

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

newbie developer here and this is actually my first question on stack overflow. I'm in my first role as a developer and I've been given the task of finishing off an app that someone else started and I'm having a hard time getting the page to refresh when the users click a particular button.

The page has a list of items and each item has a checkbox next to it that users can put a check mark into and then click the Remove Items button. In theory clicking that button is supposed to refresh the page when it's done, or at least refresh the section of the page that contains the list..as far as I can tell. And the item is being removed, but the refresh isn't working so users are having to manually refresh the page before the items they chose to remove actually disappear off the screen.

Here's what's behind the button in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdatePartStatus(List<tblPart> parts, tblArea area)
        {
            _LookupService.UpdatePartStatus(parts);
            // return RedirectToAction("Details", area);
            // return Redirect("~/Details");
            return RedirectToAction("Parts", "Menu", false);
            // <% return Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); %>
            // return Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            // return Page.Redirect(Page.Request.RawUrl, false);
            // return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            // return View();
            // return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);

        }
```

The first line that's commented out is the way the previous developer left it. All the other lines that are commented out are the things I've tried so far, none of which worked. And the one that isn't commented out just happens to be the last one I tried before posting this. Most of those attempts are the results of searching around here on stack overflow

And here's the script from the Details view:

```
<script>
    $('#btnAjax').click(function () {

            ....validation code I removed for this post....

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/Parts/UpdatePartStatus',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here's the MapRoute code that I've seen referenced in several other posts on this topic:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Parts", action = "Menu", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The last thing the previous developer said before they left was that this is all standard MVC, nothing out of the ordinary but I'm running out of ideas.

I appreciate any thoughts or advice anyone can offer.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried window.reload();  inside the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared in question does not have anything to reload the current page. Looks like you are making an ajax form submit to the server. So it does not really make sense to return a redirect response from that.

If you want to reload the page, you can do that in the `done` event of the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Parts/UpdatePartStatus',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).done(function(res){
    window.location.href = window.location.href; // This will reload the page
}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log('ajax call failed');
    });
```

**But again**, If you are reloading the page what is the point of doing the ajax post ? Instead of realoding the page, you may simply remove the specific DOM element(s) you removed using javascript. This will give the user a partial page update experience without the entire page reload.

If you know the Id of the item you removed, you can use that in your jQuery selector to remove it.

```
var idOfDeletedItem = "someDomElementId";
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Parts/UpdatePartStatus',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).done(function(res){
    // Let's remove that DOM element from the DOM
    $("#"+idOfDeletedItem).remove();

}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log('ajax call failed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shyju, I'm trying your second suggestion first since that seems to be the preferred way to do it and is, I think, what the previous developer intended. But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, this line either has one too many quotes or is missing a quote somewhere:

`$("#"+idOfDeletedItem").remove();`

So I tried a few variations both with and without but I'm not having any luck yet. You were right though there is a variable declared just above the ajax call:

`var data = { 'parts': itemsToRemove, 'area' : area };`

Can you help clarify exactly how it needs to be?

Comment: Yes. It should be `$("#"+idOfDeletedItem).remove();`. I had an extra `"`" there. I updated the answer now fix it. If you know the Id of the DOM element you can use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `success` function to the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Parts/UpdatePartStatus',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        location.reload();
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to change the behavior at all, do I also need an `error:` to go along with the `success:` or does it not care? I also tried @Jason's suggestion and typed it just the way you had it @nbokmans but I put window.reload() instead of location.reload() and that also did not seem to change the behavior at all. I appreciate the replies, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax, then you should use

```
    public JsonResult UpdatePartStatus(List<tblPart> parts, tblArea area)
    {
        _LookupService.UpdatePartStatus(parts);

        return Json(null); //This will always return a null result to your ajax call indicating a success 
    }
```

For me, I usually do return json result this way :

```
try {
    LookupService.UpdatePartStatus(parts);
    return Json(new { Success = true});
}
catch {
    return Json(new { Success = false});
}
```

And in your ajax call, do this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '/Parts/UpdatePartStatus',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) {
    if (result.Success)
        location.reload();
    } else {
        alert("Delete failed");
    }

}
})
```